# When extended session will expire?

Tags: c#, uwp, suspend

It seems if I request an extended execution session in other places of my application, not in app suspending event, the extended session is alive until I dispose it. So I wonder if I use the extended session in app suspending event, when this session will expire, is it under our control, or not? (Exclude the system resource is limit, anyway it will revoke the execution session in this case. But if the system resource is enough, will the session be revoked silently?)

I see below code [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt590969.aspx)

```
private async void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
  var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
  using (var session = new ExtendedExecutionSession())
  {
    session.Reason = ExtendedExecutionReason.SavingData;
    session.Description = "Upload Data";
    session.Revoked += session_Revoked;
    var result = await session.RequestExtensionAsync();
    if (result == ExtendedExecutionResult.Denied)
    {
      UploadBasicData();
    }
    // Upload Data
    var completionTime = await UploadDataAsync(session);
  }
  deferral.Complete();
}
```

I wonder if I don't use using statement above, and don't call deferral.Complete() here, and if I use reason as unspecific, when exactly the ExtendedExecutionSession will expire, whether my extended execution session will never expire until the resource is really low and will revoke my session execution?

Comment: I've deleted the answer with timing for [*ExtendedExecutionReason.Unspecified*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution) as it doesn't answer your question. I'm not sure how this will behave in *SavingData* reason. Only note, that saving data should be fast. Moreover, MSDN says that if you don't complete the *SavingData* and you launch the app, it will wait for previous session to complete saving.

Comment: I actually use the unsepcific reason in my app, and it seems if I request extended execution session in other points of my app, it will keep the app running and go on doing the stuff for at least 40 minutes even I minimize the app ( I tested and I see it runs for 40 minutes, maybe longer which I haven't tested so I don't know). But when I move my code into the suspending event, same code, seems it doesn't go that long. I will add log to see whether it is invoked for some reason. Thank you anyway!!!

Comment: Note that OS may kill the process for many reasons, you shouldn't depend on those timings.

Comment: On desktop devices, extended execution sessions created with ExtendedExecutionReason.Unspecified have a battery-aware time limit. If the device is connected to wall power, there is no limit to the length of the extended execution time period. If the device is on battery power, the extended execution time period can run up to ten minutes in the background. A tablet or laptop user can get the same long running behavior at the expense of battery life when the Always Allowed option is selected in Battery Usage Settings.